# Visual Studio loses/drops/deletes VB continuation lines after subroutines?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Several times while debugging a VB.Net program I have found that continuation lines are missing from a subroutine designed to handle an event.  The continuation character "_" is there but the following line is missing

Example:

```
Friend Sub TV_Main_Network_MouseDown _
    Handles TV_Main_Network.MouseDown
```

Will become

```
Friend Sub TV_Main_Network_MouseDown _
```

The first few times I figured I had made some editing error, but this has happened 3 times now, always in the same way (different subroutines but same place).   As far as I can tell, no other continuation lines have changed.

Is this a bug or some feature I have missed?

Comment: Does the program continue to compile afterwards? Are you just seeing some sort of display artifact in the debugger?

Comment: The program compiles and runs but the event becomes unhandled - very annoying.  I assume this is because the next line is blank so the continuation simply becomes meaningless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if you delete a control that the handler is based on. For example, if you have a handler for button1 and delete button1 from the form (in design mode), the "handles" part of the sub statement is automatically deleted.

This also happens when you write a handler for a control that does not exist, then add the control to the form in design mode, and then double click on that control. In this case, it adds a new handler and removes the "handles..." from the previous handler.

Comment: Really?  It works the opposite way in C#, where the handler remains, but now you get a compile error because the handler is referencing something that no longer exists.  As aggravating as that sounds, I think I like it better than the VB way.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: That's not surprising; VB's editor on the whole is smarter than C#'s editor.  Also, C# declares its event handlers in a separate file (the form's designer file) rather than declaring them in the code behind file like VB.NET does.

Comment: Would renaming a control delete the "handles...".  I renamed several controls.

Comment: There's an option for that. By default, VB goes through the entire projects and renames references to the control you just renamed. That is REALLY handy. You can even rename the file in Solution Explorer and it will rename everything for you. I'm not sure what happens if this option is disabled.